# How to read data/text from url into batch file?

Tags: batch-file

Is there anyway to read data/text from URL into batch file? 
  I am working on Windows.

I am trying to read text from following link. 
 
http://www.zeetvusa.com/schedule/?zone=Central#

More particularly now playing, so if now playing is example Show1, then I won't let me kids see the channel which will be opened in VLC player.

Comment: it'd be helpful if you said which os/shell you're on. batch suggests windows, but it's not up to us to guess that for you.

Comment: @MarcB sorry, I am working on windows.

Comment: @Mogli: It's impossible with batch file alone. You'll need third party tools to retrieve a web content and possibly also a parser since HTML files use characters that would make difficult for batch file to do by itself.

Comment: @Jay I am planning to use google docs spreadsheet to fetch the data I need from that url and I can just use third party tool to get content on to my local hard drive as a text and have dos read the file and check if it says example "Show1" in that file. does that sound doable?

Comment: cURl is a command-line tool that can retrieve data from a URL. There's a version for Windows which can be downloaded [here](http://curl.haxx.se/).

Comment: @EitanT Thanks, I am on work PC right now, I guess am having problem running cURL here. I'll try running from home PC. Thanks